# Adding caret inside a link item using jquery

Tags: jquery, list, nav

I'm trying to insert a caret after either link item i.e **List A, List B, List C, List D**. if the list(`<li class="level0">`) has more than one item in it.

**See my HTML below**

```
<nav class="navigation" data-action="navigation">
<ul class="ui-id-2">
<li class="level0"><a href="#">List A</a></li>
<li class="level0"><a href="#">List B</a></li>
<li class="level0"><a href="#">List C</a>
    <ul class="ui-id-3">
            <li class="level0"><a href="#">in A</a></li>
            <li class="level0"><a href="#">in B</a></li>
            <li class="level0"><a href="#">in C</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
<li class="level0"><a href="#">List D</a></li>

</ul>

</nav>
```

**This is what I have I have tried to do with no success**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){


 $('.navigation .level0 > a').each(function() {
        if($(this).parent('li').children('a').size() > 1 ) {
           $(this).append('<span class="dwn">▼</span>');
        }           
    });

});
```

**It's a foolish question but your help will be appreciated. Thanks.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I've put n-level example also.

```js
$('.navigation .level0 a').each(function() {
  var hasElements = $(this).closest('.level0').find('li').length>0;
        if(hasElements) {
           $(this).append('<span class="dwn">▼</span>');
        }           
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navigation" data-action="navigation">
<ul class="ui-id-2">
<li class="level0"><a href="#">List A</a></li>
<li class="level0"><a href="#">List B</a></li>
<li class="level0"><a href="#">List C</a>
    <ul class="ui-id-3">
            <li class="level0"><a href="#">in A</a>
            <ul class="ui-id-3">
            <li class="level0"><a href="#">in A</a></li>
            <li class="level0"><a href="#">in B</a></li>
            <li class="level0"><a href="#">in C</a></li>
        </ul></li>
            <li class="level0"><a href="#">in B</a></li>
            <li class="level0"><a href="#">in C</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
<li class="level0"><a href="#">List D</a></li>

</ul>

</nav>
```

**Update**
The only thing to change in your code would do this

```
$(this).closest('.level0').find('li').length
```

When you are targeting an anchor, You need to find its closest `li` element. Since this HTML structure will have list elements in nested form.

With nested I meant you can have dropdowns to n-level hierarchy (list (`li`) into list (`li`)).

So we've checked whether current anchor's closest `li` item have children elements as `li` and checked their length to be greater than 0.

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.